# Need help on dp4j

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to test private method in class. I found that with dp4j it is very easy to test private methods and I found sample code also. But that sample code is not running. I am trying to run from eclipse and dp4j.jar is already included in the build path. The example found in JUnit site is,

With dp4j.jar as a library of your project you can DIRECTLY ACCESS private methods in your tests. Reflection API code will be injected directly into the AST (i.e during compilation). For example, the following will work:

```
class Junit11 {

    private int one = 1;

    private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s) {}

}

public class JunitTest11 {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void t() {
         final int two = new Junit11().one + 1;
         org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(2, two);
         Junit11.p(two, new Double(2), "who", "said", "varargs are difficult to test with the reflection API?");
         assertEquals("generate and validate my Patterns implementations", dp4j.com);

    }

}
```

Can anybody help me to run this?

Comment: can you please describe more concretely what does not work for you?

Comment: And describe how you're running the test(s).

Comment: I am running this from eclipse. I have added dp4j.jar to the build path. But eclipse shows compilation error at the 1st & 3rd line of the method t(). But reading description in dp4j site, it seems reflection codes are generated during compile time so that one need not write any extra code to access private method during testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dp4j from Eclipse. It uses internal javac APIs. Eclipse has it's own compiler, so unless you're using maven in Eclipse, you can't use dp4j.

See the [dp4j FAQ: Does it work with Eclipse?](https://sites.google.com/a/mysimpatico.com/dp4j/faq)